# Can not navigate with Go Router when implement Navigation Widget in navigatorBuilder function

Tags: flutter, navigation, gorouter

### Description

I am trying to Navigate between screens with a Navigation Menu using [go_router plugin](https://gorouter.dev/). When I click the item in the menu, nothing happens but if I change the URL the screen does change.

[Video shows the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1emTtngDYZEVe3NLPdkQGLojn9moPrKbq/view?usp=sharing)

#### Expect

Every time I navigate back and forth, both URL and screen change

### My Code

app_router.dart

```dart
class AppRouter {
  AppRouter(this._appBloc);

  final AppBloc _appBloc;

  GoRouter get router => GoRouter(
        routes: pages.values.toList(growable: false),
        errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(
          key: state.pageKey,
        ),
        refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(_appBloc.stream),
        navigatorBuilder: _buildRouterView,
        redirect: _redirect,
      );

  String? _redirect(GoRouterState state) {
    final loggedIn = _appBloc.state.status == AppStatus.authenticated;

    final name = state.subloc;

    final loggingIn = name == '/login' || name == '/';

    if (!loggedIn) return loggingIn ? null : '/login';

    if (loggingIn) return '/app';

    return null;
  }

  static Map<String, GoRoute> pages = {
    route_names.onboard: GoRoute(
      name: route_names.onboard,
      path: routes[route_names.onboard]!,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => OnboardPage.page(key: state.pageKey),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: route_names.login.subRoutePath,
          name: route_names.login,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => LoginPage.page(key: state.pageKey),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: route_names.signUp.subRoutePath,
          name: route_names.signUp,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => LoginPage.page(key: state.pageKey),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    'app': GoRoute(
        path: '/app',

        // All /app pages get the main scaffold
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Text("App Main");
        },
        routes: [
          ExplorePage.route,
          PlanPage.route,
          AccountPage.route,
        ]),
  };

  Widget _buildRouterView(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget child) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) => BlocBuilder<AppBloc, AppState>(builder: (context, appState) {
        if (appState.status == AppStatus.unauthenticated) {
          return child;
        }
        return HomePageSkeleton(
          child: child,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

app.dart

```dart
class AppView extends StatelessWidget {
  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables
  AppView({super.key, required AppBloc appBloc}) {
    _appBloc = appBloc;
    _appRouter = AppRouter(_appBloc);
  }
  late final AppBloc _appBloc;
  late final AppRouter _appRouter;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<AppBloc, AppState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state == const AppState.unauthenticated()) {
          _appRouter.router.goNamed(route_names.login);
        }
      },
      child: MaterialApp.router(

        supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
        routeInformationParser: _appRouter.router.routeInformationParser,
        routeInformationProvider: _appRouter.router.routeInformationProvider,
        routerDelegate: _appRouter.router.routerDelegate,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

HomePageSkeleton.class

```dart
// inside build method

class HomePageSkeleton extends StatelessWidget with NavigationMixin {
  const HomePageSkeleton({Key? key,required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Responsive.isMobile(context) ? AppBottomNavigation(index: 0) : const SizedBox(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            if (Responsive.isTablet(context) || Responsive.isLaptop(context))
              // It takes 1/6 part of the screen
              Expanded(
                child: SideMenu(index: 0, onSelected: (index) => onTabSelected(index, context)),
              ),
            Expanded(
                // It takes 5/6 part of the screen
                flex: 5,
                child: child),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
//onTapSelected method

  void onTabSelected(int index, BuildContext context) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        // context.goNamed(route_names.explore);
        context.go('/app/explore');
        break;
      case 1:
        // context.goNamed(route_names.plan);
        context.go('/app/plan');
        break;
      case 2:
        // context.goNamed(route_names.account);
        context.go('/app/account');
        break;
      default:
        throw Exception('Unknown view');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my class AppRouter into:

```dart
class AppRouter {
  AppRouter(AppBloc appBloc)
      : _router = GoRouter(
          routes: getPages().values.toList(growable: false),
          errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
          ),
          refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(appBloc.stream),
          navigatorBuilder: _buildRouterView,
          redirect: (GoRouterState state) {
            _redirect(state, appBloc);
          },
        ),
        _appBloc = appBloc;

  final AppBloc _appBloc;

  final GoRouter _router;

  GoRouter get router {
    return _router;
  }
```

... and it worked

Comment: I don't understand how making this change worked for you. I am also facing the same problem so can you please explain a bit?

Comment: Based on my understanding, in the old version, every time we call the `get router {}` it recreates the router, so the screen goes blank every time.